# Fxcop plugin 1.0 Jar for sonarqube 5.6.5

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, code-coverage, fxcop, sonarqube5.6

I need the **Fxcop plugin 1.0 Jar,** I got the Fxcop plugin jar **code** from **[github](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-fxcop)** But i want the Jar. Please share the path from where i can get the Jar.

**My sonar Details**

- **Sonarqube:** 5.6.5
- **SonarC#:** 5.10
- **SonarVB:** 3.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the downloads page:
[FxCop 1.0](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-fxcop/releases/tag/1.0)

Cheers!